# Create a New Image() in 1 Line

Tags: javascript

Right now, I'm using

```
var lifeIcon = new Image();
lifeIcon.src = "img/System/lifeIcon.png";
```

Is there a way to do the same thing in 1 line?

I tried

`var lifeIcon = (new Image()).src = "img/System/lifeIcon.png";`

But it doesn't work. lifeIcon is considered as a string...

Thanks.

Note: I have many, many images. My goal is to use the Image in a canvas.
Ex: `ctx.drawImage(lifeIcon,0,0)`

---

Solution:

```
function newImage(src){
    var tmp = new Image();
    tmp.src = src;
    return tmp
}

var lifeIcon = newImage("img/System/lifeIcon.png");
var closeIcon = newImage("img/System/closeIcon.png");
var goldIcon = newImage("img/System/goldIcon.png");
...
```

Note: I personally find it faster to write and faster to read that way, especially because I have many images.

Comment: Is the class `Image` under your control? Could you add or change the constructor?

Comment: ...why? That would be terrible for readability

Comment: @Confusion It's a built-in class for the HTML `<img>` element

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sort of depends on what you're doing next. If the only other thing you need is to append it, then you can do this:

```
element.appendChild(new Image()).src = "img/System/lifeIcon.png";
```

This works because `.appendChild()` returns the newly appended element.

---

If you need to assign other properties, then you may simply want to create a helper function that lets you pass an object holding the properties and values.

```
function create(name, props) {
    var elem = document.createElement(name);
    for (var p in props)
        elem[p] = props[p];
    return elem;
}
```

This is a very simple function, and could be expanded a bit, but you get the idea.

```
var el = create("img", {src: "img/System/lifeIcon.png"});
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea of creating a custom function.

Answer (score 1):

Well, not with the `var`. You could do this if it was a global:

```
(lifeIcon = new Image()).src = "img/System/lifeIcon.png"; // WARNING: VERY BAD
```

Obviously, this is a bad idea, since you always want to keep the globals to a minimum.

Actually, the whole idea of assigning the `src` on one line is a bad idea anyway, since it would make your code much harder to read. Remember, you're going to spend more time reading your code than writing it, so use the two-line form. Your future self will thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Its difficult to do without modifying the Image function or making an external function like so.

```
function img(src) {
  var img = new Image(); img.src = src;
  var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
  var returning = img.onload = function() {
    canvas.width = img.width;
    canvas.height = img.height;
    canvas.getContext("2d").drawImage(img, 0, 0);
    return canvas;
  }();
  return returning;
}
```

This will give you a canvas ready for you to draw it on another canvas.

```
ctx.drawImage(img("background.jpg"), 0, 0);
```

OR Just

```
var image = img("background.jpg"); #will give you a canvas
```

What else you could try for one_lining is the following

```
var image = function() { var img = new Image(); img.src = "background.jpg"; return img; }();
```

One lining in my opinion is only perfect if you call it 1 or 2 times, but if you heavily use this then simply making a function will do better.

Good luck ^^